# Host-listener click event not working in bing-maps v8 in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, bing-maps

**In Firefox 'document: click' event is not working on bing-maps v8.** I have one scenario in my application in which I have integrated context-menu package with bing maps-v8 which will open on right-click of pushpin and closes on left click, but 'click' event is not working when clicking on bing maps(here I am talking about default mouse click event not bing map attached click event) and due to which context-menu is not closing.
I have option to manually close context-menu by adding click event listener of bing maps but context-menu should work according to its default behaviour which should close automatically after detecting click event.

**Whereas in chrome it's working properly without any issues.**

To set the environment please goto [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bing-maps?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbing-map.component.ts). And copy below code in bing-map.component.ts and run the example and open in firefox as well as in chrome.
you will notice that click is firing in chrome but not in firefox.

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener("document:click", ["$event"])
public closeMenu(event: MouseEvent): void {
if (event.type === "click" && event.button === 0) {
   alert("mouse clicked.");
   }
}
```

Comment: It works for me in firefox, so cannot reproduce this

Comment: @PierreDuc, It is working with latest version of Firefox (may be 69+). But I have tested with lower version (56 & 63) and in that it was not working

Comment: than it's more or less a non issue. That's less than 1% of the current used browsers and it's probably a bug from firefox